# RichTextEdit box in UWP

Tags: uwp, rtf, windows-10-mobile

I use this code from MSDN for displaying rtf in Windows 10 apps.

[image: MSDN screenshot]

It works good on my PC, but i have problem in Windows 10 mobile. I have rtf document with size 300kb. PC reads and displays it very fast, but phone complete the task around 10 sec. Other controls are unavailable when my app loads text to the RichEditBox. Phone can't show it immediately.

How can i save it? Help me please!

Comment: It would be helpful to add the code to the question, instead of linking to a screenshot with the code. It allows everybody to easily see the code without leaving the site and the code is covered in search

Comment: The problem is most likely the LoadFromStream method call.  I'd break that call up to also be asynchronous.

Comment: Did you test your code on mobile device or on mobile emulator? I can't reproduce your problem on emulator, I tested to load a fast 3000KB rtf file, the text is shown very quickly.